# form validation not working, for gettting submitted without being validated

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i dont understand what am i doing wrong here.... tried almost everything still the form is being submitted without validation. i dont know what's causing the problem here been working on this for past 4 hours, everytime i click on the submit button it goes straight to the submission successful page... can anyone help me with this?

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function validate(){
if(document.orderForm.firstName.value=="" ){
document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = "Please Enter a First Name";
document.orderForm.fistName.focus();
return (false);
}
if(document.orderForm.lastName.value == "" ){
document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = "Please Enter a Last Name";
document.orderForm.lastName.focus();
return (false);
}
if(document.orderForm.address.value == "" ){
document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = "Please Enter a address");
document.orderForm.address.focus();
return (false);
}
if(document.orderForm.city.value == "" ){
document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = "Please Enter a City");
document.orderForm.city.focus();
return (false);
}
if(document.orderForm.postalCode.value == "" ||
document.orderForm.postalCode.value.length != 6 ){
document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = "Please Enter a correct PostalCode");
document.orderForm.postalCode.focus(); 
return (false);
}
if(document.orderForm.province.value == "Select" ){
document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = "Please Select your province")
return (false);
}
if(document.orderForm.widget1qty.value == "0" || document.orderForm.widget1qty.value == "" &&
document.orderForm.widget2qty.value == "0" || document.orderForm.widget2qty.value == "" &&
document.orderForm.widget2qty.value == "0" || document.orderForm.widget2qty.value == "" ){
document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = "Please Select at least one item")
return (false);
}
else
{
return(true);
}
}
</script>



    <form name="orderForm" method="POST" action="processForm.html" onSubmit="return validate();">
```

Comment: Check out this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp) for form validation.

Comment: you have several syntax errors in your validate function, like `document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = "Please Enter a address");` , in this you have closing bracket at the end.

Comment: fixed the errors, still not working

Comment: i know, its because the default value of the field is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer this Sample code,definitely Solve your problem

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validate()
{
   if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )
   {
      document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "Please enter first name";
     document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   return( true );
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="processForm.html" name="myForm"  onsubmit="return(validate());">
 <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">
 <tr>
   <td align="right">Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>

 <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
<div id="errors"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: the only thing is that it doesnt show a list of errors, it only shows one error at a time. like if its the first name missing it will show firstname error only then it will go to last name to check if it is missing, do you know how do show a full list of errors on the page?

Comment: you need to code function for Showallerrors then append to the html elements.

Answer (score -2):

Please use below code. it is working fine.

```
function validate() {
  if (document.orderForm.firstName.value=="" ) {
    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = `Please enter first name`;
    document.getElementById("firstName").focus();
    return (false);
  }
}


<form name="orderForm"  onSubmit="return validate();">
  <input type="text" id="firstName" />
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
  <div id="errors"></div>
</form>
```

http://www.sharepointprog.com

Comment: How does this differ from the OP's posted sample?

Comment: still it submits the from sucessfully